# Set Range of Bits in a ushort

Tags: c#, c++, bit-manipulation

Lets say I have a ushort value that I would like to set bits 1 to 4 inclusive (assuming 0 is the LSB and 15 is the MSB).

In C++ you could define a struct that mapped out specific bits:

```
struct KibblesNBits
{
   unsigned short int TheStart: 1;
   unsigned short int TheMeat:  4;
   unsigned short int TheRest: 11;
}
```

Then you could assign a value to 'TheMeat' directly.  I'm looking to do something similar in C#.  Ideally, I would like a funcion definition that looked like this:

```
public ModValue SetRange<ModValue, RangeValue>(ModValue valueToMod, int startIndex, int endIndex, RangeValue rangeValueToAssign)
```

It would also need to valide that the rangeValueToAssign does not exceed the maximum size (assuming values are unsigned from 0 to max).  So if the range is from 1 to 4, this is 4 bits, range would be from 0 to 15.  If it is outside these limits, throw an exception.

I didnt find anything in the BitConverter class that could do something like this.  Best I could think of was using manaul shift operators.  Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: A non generic version might look something like this:

```
  public static ushort SetRange(ushort valueToMod, int startIndex, int endIndex, ushort rangeValueToAssign)
  {
     // Determine max value
     ushort max_value = Convert.ToUInt16(Math.Pow(2.0, (endIndex - startIndex) + 1.0) - 1);
     if(rangeValueToAssign > max_value) throw new Exception("Value To Large For Range");
     // Shift the value and add it to the orignal (effect of setting range?)
     ushort value_to_add = (ushort)(rangeValueToAssign << startIndex);
     return (ushort)(valueToMod + value_to_add);
  }
```

Where:

```
ushort new_val = SetRange(120, 1, 2, 3);
```

would result in 'new_val' being set to 126.

Comment: Whats wrong with shift operators? they would provide the best performance here...

Comment: @TJMonk15 - I guess nothing is wrong with them, just looking for a generic solution or seeing if there was a different way to do it that I am just missing

Comment: Please post a snippet of code illustrating how you would like to use this device.  I'm still a little unclear as to what you want SetRange to do, exactly.

Comment: @John - Ok I added a non generic example of what I'm trying to accomplish.  Let me know if you still have more questions

Comment: @SwDevMan: Actually, given your clarification, unless I'm missing something I think you're non-generic sample is a pretty good implementation.  Just templatize it and your done!  Am I missing something?

Comment: @SwDevMan81: just so you know, your non generic implementation doesnt actually set those bits. If any of those bits are already set, it wont prodcue the correct result. Let me post a fix as an answer...

Comment: @TJMonk15 - Yeah I figured it wasn't exactly correct because I just threw it together for an example for John Dibling. Thanks for your post with something non-generic that works. I feel like there should be a way to make a generic function that accepts various types. If not I guess I'll just have to use function overloading, but I really didnt want to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed type answers here helped me get to a generic solution as originally requested. Here's the final code (with a getter bonus).

```
/// <summary>Gets the bit array value from the specified range in a bit vector.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the bit vector. Must be of type <see cref="IConvertible"/>.</typeparam>
/// <param name="bits">The bit vector.</param>
/// <param name="startIdx">The zero-based start index of the bit range to get.</param>
/// <param name="count">The number of sequential bits to fetch starting at <paramref name="startIdx"/>.</param>
/// <returns>The value of the requested bit range.</returns>
public static T GetBits<T>(T bits, byte startIdx, byte count) where T : IConvertible
{
    if (startIdx >= (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) * 8)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIdx));
    if (count + startIdx > (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) * 8)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType((bits.ToInt64(null) >> startIdx) & ((1 << count) - 1), typeof(T));
}

/// <summary>Sets the bit values at the specified range in a bit vector.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the bit vector. Must be of type <see cref="IConvertible"/>.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the value. Must be of type <see cref="IConvertible"/>.</typeparam>
/// <param name="bits">The bit vector.</param>
/// <param name="startIdx">The zero-based start index of the bit range to set.</param>
/// <param name="count">The number of sequential bits to set starting at <paramref name="startIdx"/>.</param>
/// <param name="value">The value to set within the specified range of <paramref name="bits"/>.</param>
public static void SetBits<T, TValue>(ref T bits, byte startIdx, byte count, TValue value) where T : IConvertible where TValue : IConvertible
{
    if (startIdx >= (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) * 8)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIdx));
    if (count + startIdx > (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) * 8)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
    var val = value.ToInt64(null);
    if (val >= (1 << count)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));
    bits = (T)Convert.ChangeType(bits.ToInt64(null) & ~(((1 << count) - 1) << startIdx) | (val << startIdx), typeof(T));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int SetRange(int num, int from, int to, int value)
{
    if (from < 0 || from > to || to >= 32) throw new ArgumentException("from/to are not valid");
    if (value >= (2 << (to - from)) && (to - from < 31)) throw new ArgumentException("value is too large");
    return num & ~(((2 << to) - 1) - ((1 << from) - 1)) | (value << from);
}
```

No for-loops or Math.Pow (which is amazingly slow, way slower than Sin/Cos etc).

As for generic - sorry, that won't work. There is no base type for numbers in C# (or .NET), so this is simply impossible. It looks like you're trying to use generics like template functions in C++ - don't be fooled by the similar looks; they are completely different.

If you must have different types, I'd suggest overloads instead.

```
public static int SetRange(int num, int from, int to, int value)
{
    if (from < 0 || from > to || to >= 32) throw new ArgumentException("from/to are not valid");
    if (value >= (2 << (to - from)) && (to - from < 31)) throw new ArgumentException("value is too large");
    return num & ~(((2 << to) - 1) - ((1 << from) - 1)) | (value << from);
}

public static ushort SetRange(ushort num, int from, int to, ushort value)
{
    if (from < 0 || from > to || to >= 16) throw new ArgumentException("from/to are not valid");
    if (value >= (2 << (to - from))) throw new ArgumentException("value is too large");
    return (ushort) (num & ~(((2 << to) - 1) - ((1 << from) - 1)) | (value << from));
}
```

However, in C# it might be more idiomatic to just always use int (or long if you need that).

Answer (score 0):

If you want that type of access, consider a `BitVector32` or `BitArray`, or get familiar with bitwise arithmetic. You *can* do explicit layout of structs in C# (causing a union), but I don't think it is to your advantage. It is primarily aimed at interop scenarios.

For info, the bitwise operators work mainly on `uint`/`int`/`ulong`/`long` - not so much the smaller integer types.

Comment: @Marc - Thanks, do you know off hand if either of those have a SetRange feature that I am looking for.  I dont see anything in the msdn pages for either.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 - no but you could write an extension method for them easily enough?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any language feature (apart from manually shifting bits around) that would achieve this.

The only thing that comes to my mind is the old [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) from .NET 1.1. But you can only manipulate individual bits, not ranges of bits.

So, no.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a fix for your update:

```
  public static ushort SetRange(ushort valueToMod, int startIndex, int endIndex, ushort rangeValueToAssign)
  {
     // Determine max value
     ushort max_value = Convert.ToUInt16(Math.Pow(2.0, (endIndex - startIndex) + 1.0) - 1);
     if(rangeValueToAssign > max_value) throw new Exception("Value To Large For Range");
     // Clear our bits where we want to "Set" the value for
     for( int i=startIndex; i<endIndex; i++ )
         valueToMod &= ~(1<<i);
     // Shift the value and add it to the orignal (effect of setting range?)
     ushort value_to_add = (ushort)(rangeValueToAssign << startIndex);
     return (ushort)(valueToMod + value_to_add);
  }
```

Comment: Nice, ok now just make it generic and I'm sold

Comment: Ghhh! Math.Pow? Ugly! Use bitwise shift (like in your for loop) instead.