# new to java: what are the bits between i and j in 10000000000

Tags: java, android, algorithm, bit

I have been asked to solved the following [problem](http://martinm2w.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/5-1bits-set-i-to-j-bit-in-n-equal-to-m/):

You are given two 32-bit numbers, N and M, and two bit positions, i and j. Write a method to set all bits between i and j in N equal to M (e.g., M becomes a substring of N located at i and starting at j). 
EXAMPLE: 
Input: N = 10000000000, M = 10101, i = 2, j = 6 
Output: N = 10001010100

what I dont understand, is what are the bits between i and j in 10000000000 ? can you explain this for me ?

I have familarity with bitwise operations, but this has totally confused me.

Comment: From your example, the bits having values between 2^i and 2^j, inclusive.  You will probably want some combination of shifts, bitmasks, and OR's.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Range of Bits in a ushort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246228/set-range-of-bits-in-a-ushort)

Comment: I don't think this is totally answerable, because we don't know where 0 is-  if its using LSB or MSB (least significant bit or most significant bit) first.

Comment: @GabeSechan - we do know, from the example.

Comment: Ah, good point.  Its LSB

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - not a duplicate, the actual question here is not the mechanism for implementing it, but rather one about understanding  "what are the bits between i and j in 10000000000 ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example, looks like the bits are numbered right to left, starting at 0:

```
N             1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Position #   10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
                      ^       ^                      
                     j=6     i=2
                      \_______/
                          |
                  These are the bits
                 between i and j in N.
```

Comment: +1 For clear and simple example addressing the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the digits in N is 1 bit.  Starting from the right-most as 0, count the digits and move over i digits.  That's the beginning of the bits you're looking for.  Do the same for j.  That's the end.   The substring between i and j are the bits to replace.

Answer (score 0):

To set a bit you can OR it into a value.

To remove/zero a bit you can AND it out of a value.

So lets assume low *i* and *j* means the least significant bits. This is reasonable.

Now you have

```
N = 10000000000
j = 6 --^   ^--  i = 2
M = 10101
```

Start by setting bit *i* to the value of the least bit, bit 0, in M. 1.

To set bit 2 in N like bit 0 in M you can simply

```
int bitToSet = 1<<i; // value of least bit i

if ( M % 2 == 1 ) // least bit is set
   N = N | bitToSet;
else
   N = N | ~bitToSet; // negate to remove
M /= 2; // move up to next higher bit
```

Rinse and repeat to *j*.